# How to prove $(|x_1|+\cdots+|x_n|)^p=2^p(|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p)$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be real numbers. I'm pretty sure that $(|x_1|+\cdots+|x_n|)^p=2^p(|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p)$. But I have no idea how to prove it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unfortunately is not true in general; observe that $(1+2)^3=27\neq{}2^3(1+8)$; and particularly that for any positive integers with an odd sum, the left hand side is odd, but when $p>0$, the right hand side is even, so the equation does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Surely false. Take $x_i=1$ for all $i$ and $p=1$.